# How does awk -F work?

Tags: awk

Can you please explain as to how the followin piece of code works?

```
l_Basename="hello_world.ksh"

l_THIS_FILE=`echo $l_Basename | awk -F. '{field=1
             while (field < NF) {
                 printf $field
                 if (field < NF - 1) {
                     printf "."}
                 field++} 
             printf "\n"}'`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-F.` sets [the Field Separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Field-Separator.html) to `.`: Given a  line `a.b.c.`, awk will see four fields: `a`, `b`, `c`, and  (an empty field).

```
field=1
while (field < NF) 
{
     printf $field
     if (field < NF - 1) 
     {
         printf "."
     }
     field++
}
```

- The code loops over each field and prints it. Note that `field` begins with 1, as field 0 is the entire line (or [record](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html), to be precise). Since the check is [`< NF`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-NF-variable-1), it never reaches the last field.
- Until the second-last field, it adds a `.`, presumably as a field separator for some other program to handle.

---

All told this code is a convoluted way of implementing [`basename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/basename), a command often used to strip the extension from a filename:

```
$ basename hello_world.ksh .ksh
hello_world
```

Even in `awk`, a more concise way would be to decrement the number of fields by one: `NF--`, and set the Output Field Separator to `.`, so that it gets automatically added between fields:

```
$ echo hello_world.ksh | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{NF--}1'
hello_world
```

Answer (score 2):

The "-F" option allows changing Awk's "field separator" character. Awk regards each line of input data as composed of multiple "fields", which are essentially words separated by blank spaces. A blank space (or a tab character) is the default "field separator". In some cases, the input data may be divided by another character, for example, a ":", and it would be nice to be able to tell Awk to use a different field separator. This is what the "-F" option does. To invoke Awk and specify a ":" as the field separator, we write:

`awk -F:  ...`

In this case, the field separator is a "."